# Align label contents after checkbox css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have styled Checkbox from **[this source](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0lN4G)** as below:

```css
.toggle-button {
    margin: 0 20px;
}


/*
   * Toggle button styles
   */

.toggle-button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
}

.toggle-button label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
}

.toggle-button input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button__icon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 35%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--tuli label {
    line-height: 20px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon {
    background: #fff;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 146, 236);
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    top: 35%;
    background: #0175b2;
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg) scale(0.6, 1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    transform: translate(4px, 6px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.toggle-button--tuli:hover input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)~.toggle-button__icon {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-button toggle-button--tuli">
  <input id="toggleButton11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggleButton11">I confirm that I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#2c6ed7">Terms of Use</a> specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox</label>
  <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet you can see that when label contents break the line it comes below the checkbox. How can I modify the css to align label contents to appear after the checkbox. I've tried `text-indent` but that only works for 1st line. Hope to find some help.

Comment: awork around could be remove `.toggle-button--tuli label : text-indent: 30px; ` and add `.toggle-button--tuli label : padding-left: 30px; `

Comment: @Ylama That really worked.. But am confused to accept between the answers specified below.. As both `padding-left` and `margin-left` works..

Comment: go for padding :)

Comment: you should select the padding one, the margin have some issue ;) try clicking on the box and you will see

Comment: @Ylama I agree.. I noticed.. thank  you so much guys.. :) Happy coding..

Comment: @TemaniAfif Agreed.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `text-indent` use `padding-left` and it will work as you wish:

```css
.toggle-button {
    margin: 0 20px;
}


/*
   * Toggle button styles
   */

.toggle-button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
}

.toggle-button label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
}

.toggle-button input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button__icon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 35%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--tuli label {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon {
    background: #fff;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 146, 236);
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    top: 35%;
    background: #0175b2;
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg) scale(0.6, 1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    transform: translate(4px, 6px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.toggle-button--tuli:hover input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)~.toggle-button__icon {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-button toggle-button--tuli">
  <input id="toggleButton11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggleButton11">I confirm that I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#2c6ed7">Terms of Use</a> specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox</label>
  <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best answer i think!

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `text-indent` and instead use `padding-left` that should work.

```css
.toggle-button {
    margin: 0 20px;
}


/*
   * Toggle button styles
   */

.toggle-button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
}

.toggle-button label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
}

.toggle-button input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button__icon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 35%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--tuli label {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon {
    background: #fff;
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 146, 236);
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    top: 35%;
    background: #0175b2;
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg) scale(0.6, 1);
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
    transform: translate(4px, 6px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.toggle-button--tuli:hover input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)~.toggle-button__icon {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-button toggle-button--tuli">
  <input id="toggleButton11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggleButton11">I confirm that I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#2c6ed7">Terms of Use</a> specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox</label>
  <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
</div>
```

I've updated the answer. `padding-left` will allow the click to to be detected.

Comment: we cannot click on the checkbox

Comment: Sorry about that, it seems `padding-left` is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

For the `label`, use padding instead of `text-indent`:

```
.toggle-button--tuli label {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

It will add padding left for the text and the button will be aligned to the left side because it is positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.toggle-button {
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #504d4d
}

.toggle-button__icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none
}
.toggle-button label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left
}

.toggle-button input {
  display: none
}



.toggle-button--tuli label {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px
}

.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button__icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 35%;
  transition: .2s ease-out
}
.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon {
  background: #fff
}

.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggle-button__icon:after {
  opacity: 1
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border: 2px solid #2592ec;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 35%;
  background: #0175b2;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: left center
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:before {
  transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg) scale(0.6, 1)
}

.toggle-button--tuli .toggle-button__icon:after {
  transform: translate(4px, 6px) rotate(-45deg)
}

.toggle-button--tuli:hover input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)~.toggle-button__icon {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-button toggle-button--tuli">
  <input id="toggleButton11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggleButton11">I confirm that I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#2c6ed7">Terms of Use</a> specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox</label>
  <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
</div>
```

Here you go

Comment: we cannot click on the box

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> I confirm that I have read and agree to the Terms 
 of Use specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox
  I confirm that I have read and agree to the Terms 
 of Use specified by the client and some long text to continue with to show the alignment below checkbox</label>
  </div>
```

Try this code..